# Dreamspark Multiple Copies of VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dreamspark

On the Dreamspark website, it states that some software cannot be downloaded and installed multiple times because the product key is one-time use. However, I would like to install VS 2010 Professional on a desktop and on my laptop which I can bring to class (if I'm going to be forced to use VS, I want to use the real one).

On the other hand, the installation of VS 2010 Professional on my desktop did not require me to enter a product key at any point. Was the product key implicitly activated during the installation?

In short, is it possible to install multiple copies of Visual Studio 2010 Professional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use the installation several times. The keys generated in MS Dreamspark are from a database of pre-set keys so you'll be fine.

When installing VS 2010 from dreamspark, it gives you a 30 day trial, you are able to insert your key at the Help menu of VS 2010 to activate it.

Comment: It didn't seem like it gave me a 30 day trial, as in when it boots up it says its licensed to Microsoft. I can't check now though as I don't have access to the desktop.

Comment: O that might be it, I remember on one of my laptops it said that too, I guess it's just a Microsoft Licensed key so obviously projects' meta data won't be in your name it will be in Microsofts. But to answer the question, you can use the same key on multiple installations if it asks you for a key in the first place!

Comment: "you can use the same key on multiple installations if it asks you for a key in the first place" - It doesn't, though.

Comment: You should be ok anyway.

Comment: Haha, just went back and read the download page - "No product key is required for this download." I guess it will work fine :D I did go and do a check and some of the other products do require keys; I guess those are the ones you can't install more than once.